# Initializing section header doesn't mark sub cells as initialization cell

Tags: scripting, initialization

I have some definitions organised into Chapter>Section>subsections etc in a notebook. I wish to run this code in wolframscript so I tried (following advise from various question on SE) exporting it as both `.wls` and `.m`. Before doing so I marked the top level header as an initialization cell.

1. Marking the top level cell as initialization cell doesn't mark all sub cells as initialization cells. Why is this so? How to mark multiple cells as initialization cells at once?
2. So I selected all the cells by hand, then formatted them as `Code`(Alt+8 on windows) which defaults to initialization cell. However the code still doesn't do anything when run.

Here's a sample code

```
ClearAll@"myFunc";
myFunc := "HelloWorld";
Print@myFunc;
```

organised as

[image]

Here's the converted `.m` file. I sense it shouldn't look like this but more like the sample code  above. If so how to correctly convert `.nb`  to `.m`?(I just used *Save As* on windows)

**Code.m**

```
(* Content-type: application/vnd.wolfram.mathematica *)

(*** Wolfram Notebook File ***)
(* http://www.wolfram.com/nb *)

(* CreatedBy='Mathematica 12.0' *)

(*CacheID: 234*)
(* Internal cache information:
NotebookFileLineBreakTest
NotebookFileLineBreakTest
NotebookDataPosition[       158,          7]
NotebookDataLength[      3912,        127]
NotebookOptionsPosition[      2544,         89]
NotebookOutlinePosition[      3030,        108]
CellTagsIndexPosition[      2987,        105]
WindowFrame->Normal*)

(* Beginning of Notebook Content *)
Notebook[{

Cell[CellGroupData[{
Cell["code", "Chapter",
 InitializationCell->True,
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.8089001119785347`*^9, 3.808900112882482*^9}, {
  3.8089001589284787`*^9, 
  3.8089001594524755`*^9}},ExpressionUUID->"5fb15bd4-6b20-4087-98d0-\
0012e193112a"],

Cell[CellGroupData[{

Cell["HelloWorld", "Section",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.8089001173754773`*^9, 3.808900118162509*^9}, {
  3.8089001643834763`*^9, 
  3.808900177890507*^9}},ExpressionUUID->"4d1d36ae-2038-4788-adcb-\
c021cfee5bf9"],

Cell[CellGroupData[{

Cell["myFunc", "Subsection",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.808900121539483*^9, 3.808900122150524*^9}, {
  3.8089001680364757`*^9, 
  3.808900174319518*^9}},ExpressionUUID->"a82f67a8-c4dd-4a81-b2e3-\
8eda31e9778a"],

Cell[BoxData[{
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"ClearAll", "@", "\"\<myFunc\>\""}], ";"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"myFunc", ":=", "\"\<HelloWorld\>\""}], ";"}]}], "Input",
 InitializationCell->True,
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.8089001241164756`*^9, 3.808900146632519*^9}},
 CellLabel->
  "In[320]:=",ExpressionUUID->"d8c24f3c-5f62-46d5-a7bc-1ed9496ea181"]
}, Open  ]]
}, Open  ]]
}, Open  ]],

Cell[CellGroupData[{

Cell["execution", "Chapter",
 InitializationCell->True,
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.8089001833964815`*^9, 
  3.808900184897488*^9}},ExpressionUUID->"2056d351-d147-41b3-b78f-\
da898c685dac"],

Cell[CellGroupData[{

Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"Print", "@", "myFunc"}], ";"}]], "Input",
 InitializationCell->True,
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.8089001873274755`*^9, 3.8089001920424776`*^9}},
 CellLabel->
  "In[322]:=",ExpressionUUID->"6c3a52cd-d1e5-4f6d-b7f2-a869824ca46a"],

Cell[BoxData["\<\"HelloWorld\"\>"], "Print",
 CellChangeTimes->{3.8089003295646453`*^9},
 CellLabel->
  "During evaluation of \
In[322]:=",ExpressionUUID->"613fc7c9-dba2-4c8f-a346-5418573a39d8"]
}, Open  ]],

Cell[BoxData[""], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.8088974579201937`*^9, 
  3.8088974593101983`*^9}},ExpressionUUID->"cd50b585-47fd-48db-b720-\
2e7a35b0304a"]
}, Open  ]]
},
WindowSize->{1920, 970},
WindowMargins->{{-11, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}},
TaggingRules->{
 "ToolsOpen" -> False, "StatusMessage" -> "", 
  "SubmissionReviewData" -> {"Review" -> False}},
Magnification:>2.1 Inherited,
FrontEndVersion->"12.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 8, 2019)",
StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"
]
(* End of Notebook Content *)

(* Internal cache information *)
(*CellTagsOutline
CellTagsIndex->{}
*)
(*CellTagsIndex
CellTagsIndex->{}
*)
(*NotebookFileOutline
Notebook[{
Cell[CellGroupData[{
Cell[580, 22, 231, 5, 142, "Chapter",ExpressionUUID->"5fb15bd4-6b20-4087-98d0-0012e193112a",
 InitializationCell->True],
Cell[CellGroupData[{
Cell[836, 31, 208, 4, 139, "Section",ExpressionUUID->"4d1d36ae-2038-4788-adcb-c021cfee5bf9"],
Cell[CellGroupData[{
Cell[1069, 39, 205, 4, 111, "Subsection",ExpressionUUID->"a82f67a8-c4dd-4a81-b2e3-8eda31e9778a"],
Cell[1277, 45, 358, 8, 135, "Input",ExpressionUUID->"d8c24f3c-5f62-46d5-a7bc-1ed9496ea181",
 InitializationCell->True]
}, Open  ]]
}, Open  ]]
}, Open  ]],
Cell[CellGroupData[{
Cell[1696, 60, 183, 4, 142, "Chapter",ExpressionUUID->"2056d351-d147-41b3-b78f-da898c685dac",
 InitializationCell->True],
Cell[CellGroupData[{
Cell[1904, 68, 256, 6, 94, "Input",ExpressionUUID->"6c3a52cd-d1e5-4f6d-b7f2-a869824ca46a",
 InitializationCell->True],
Cell[2163, 76, 194, 4, 45, "Print",ExpressionUUID->"613fc7c9-dba2-4c8f-a346-5418573a39d8"]
}, Open  ]],
Cell[2372, 83, 156, 3, 60, "Input",ExpressionUUID->"cd50b585-47fd-48db-b720-2e7a35b0304a"]
}, Open  ]]
}
]
*)
```

And here's the command I used to execute it

```
wolframscript -file Code.m
```

**Env**

Windows 10
Mathematica 12.0
WolframScript 1.4.0 for Windows-x86-64